# Angular 8: HttpClient - send long string

Tags: angular, httpclient

The following code is used to send a long string to the server.

```js
this.http.post (TGT_IP,body, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).subscribe(
      (val) => {
          console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", 
                      val);
      },
      response => {
          console.log("POST call in error", response);
      },
      () => {
          console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
      });
```

I'm using my own HTTP server. Basically, this server receives a TCP message and parses it.

When I'm sending an 826 bytes body length, the server receives the headers  + data.
When the body is twice long, the server receives only the headers.
Can you please explain why ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: Can you post the request body as shown in the developer console?